# Alphabetic characters issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, character

I have to use Turkish characters, when I write "chcp" in cmd, I see 857.
So I tried to start my programs with:

```
# -*- coding: cp857 -*-
```

but nothing changed.Still I cant see Turkish characters like "ş,İ,Ş,Ğ" etc.

So I tried to start my programs with:

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
```

with this,I can see the Turkish characters,**BUT** when my program needs data from user, I cant see the Turkish characters again so my program is nothing. its like:

```
name=raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print name
--------
Please enter your name: Ayşe
A*/8e
```

so,if I have to find user's name in a list in my program, I cant find "Ayşe" because program doesnt understand Turkish characters, but it shows Turkish characters at the beginning of program.The problem appears when I need data from user.. 
It doesnt make any sense, I really want to know why and how can I fix it.I tried tons of methods,none of them works..

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [How to read Unicode input and compare Unicode strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477061/how-to-read-unicode-input-and-compare-unicode-strings-in-python), it should help you understand why raw_input isn't reading the name as you expect.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u015f' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) I got this error when I tried that method you posted my friend

Answer (score 0):

1. type chcp 65001 in console
2. right click the cmd window and change fonts to Lucida console

This is a duplicate of [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Also, you should really avoid users writing to console, it creates unnecessary complication to both you and the user