# How to decode unicode string to unicode value

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode

I have a program in Python 2.7 that does the following:

1. Ask the user for input (In Non English characters. E.g. Hebrew, English)
2. Split each character of the sentence in a list. (The input can be a small paragraph, or an email)
3. Convert the characters to Unicode values. So in the end every item of the list is a unicode escape char e.g. `"u/0391"` that can be manipulate it as string.

Ι started quite well but I can't split the letters in the array nor print the right unicode value.

```
Gr_text = unicode(raw_input("Type your message below:\n"), 'unicode-escape')

Gr = Gr_text.split()

print Gr
```

Example input:

Ενα απλο παραδειγμα.

The input (translate as "A simple example") is in Greek language without intonations. This sentence should be transform in a list as

```
['\u0395', '\u03bd', '\u03b1','\u0020', '\u03b1', '\u03c0', '\u03bb', '\u03bf','\u0020', '\u03c0', '\u03b1', '\u03c1', '\u03b1', '\u03b4', '\u03b5', '\u03b9', '\u03b3', '\u03bc', '\u03b1','\u0020',]
```

To point out I also want to convert spaces and special characters.
Then I get every letter of the list as string of unicode and not as simple letter so I can manipulate and give it other value.

Comment: Please give an example of the input and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: You need to consider the order you're doing things, and also realize that Python 2.7 doesn't input Unicode characters - you'll need to use `decode`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it works for me but your mileage may vary.

```
import sys, locale

Gr_text = raw_input('Type your message below:\n').decode(sys.stdin.encoding or locale.getpreferredencoding(True))

Gr = Gr_text.split()

print Gr
```

“Full Disclosure” credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/477496/1427800

Comment: thank you, but you miss something. I want to manipulate every letter of a word in an item in the list. When i type `for i in Gr:
 for x in i:
  h = unicode(x)
  manipulate_every_unicode letter()` can't get in str h  the unicode value.