# regexp_tokenize and Arabic text

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm using [`regexp_tokenize()`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html) to return tokens from an Arabic text without any punctuation marks:

```
import re,string,sys
from nltk.tokenize import  regexp_tokenize

def PreProcess_text(Input):
  tokens=regexp_tokenize(Input, r'[،؟!.؛]\s*', gaps=True)
  return tokens

H = raw_input('H:')
Cleand= PreProcess_text(H)
print  '\n'.join(Cleand)
```

It worked fine, but the problem is when I try to print the text.

The output for the text `ايمان،سعد`:

```
    ?يم
    ?ن
    ?
    ?
    ?
```

but if the text is in English, even with an Arabic punctuation marks, it prints the right result.

The output for the text `hi،eman`:

```
     hi
     eman
```

Comment: What's the expected output for your Arabic text?

Comment: Its probably the fact that Arabic is printed backwards. In perl, I get output of ايمان
 and ،سعد

Comment: You use Python 2.x, don't you? In Python 3.4, I get `ايمان` and `سعد` when I enter `ايمان،سعد`

Comment: the expected out put should be: ايمان سعد (the same as you)... yes think the problem is that i'm using python 2.7

Comment: Please use `@`+username to notify a user of your feedback. I suggest using `u` prefix: `ur'[\u060C\u061F!.\u061B]\s*'` and do not pass just `H` - try either `unicode(H, "utf-8")` or `H.decode('utf8')`

Comment: Any news? Did you manage to get it to work?  BTW, are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew first i tried using either unicode(H, "utf-8") or H.decode('utf8') but  these is an error in the printing. I think the solution is to change to Python 3. if you know how on Mac that will be very helpful. THANK YOU

Comment: I think you can check https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html. Also, I am sure you have not checked everything in Python 2.x. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477061/how-to-read-unicode-input-and-compare-unicode-strings-in-python

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank so much for your help, somehow the H.decode('utf8') worked perfectly!!! thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `raw_input`, the symbols are coded as bytes.

You need to convert it into a Unicode string with

```
H.decode('utf8')
```

And you may keep your regex:

```
tokens=regexp_tokenize(Input, r'[،؟!.؛]\s*', gaps=True)
```