# How to capture the string which is the output of print

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode, non-ascii-characters

Motivation:

```
s =  诶
```

This is not an ASCII character, and we need to throw an error saying something like
'The string  诶 cannot be encoded using the encoding ASCII

But if we do something like,

```
raise UnicodeEncodeError('The string %s cannot be encoded using the encoding 
%s',%(s, encoding))
```

The above would reraise the error.
but if we just do without specifying any encoding:

```
print(s)
诶
```

I guess this is because it just dumps the bytes to string.

Also something like this would raise error:

```
print ('{}'.format(str(s)))
```

and the below gives the unicode conversion:

```
 print('%s' ,%repr(s))
 u'\u8bf6'
```

is there a way to get the text which was the original text in the Error output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Unicode input and compare Unicode strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477061/how-to-read-unicode-input-and-compare-unicode-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is Python 2.7?

Try this:

```
raise UnicodeEncodeError(u'The string %s cannot be encoded using the encoding 
                         %s' %(s, encoding))
```

The point being, that the `u'...'` literal is a unicode literal - so you can actually have unicode characters in it, without having to try to encode the unicode character to ascii.

Also note that when applying `str(s)`, you are converting it back to ascii. So instead, do this:

```
print(u'{}'.format(s))
```

EDIT: The first example (`UnicodeEncodeError`) doesn't actually work, as @StephenRauch pointed out - I'm leaving it in here after fixing the syntax error...

Comment: What does the `,%` do?

Comment: @StephenRauch ah. I just copied that from OP. I've edited it to be more sane, but it seems `UnicodeEncodeError` takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given). Augh! Serves me right for not testing ;-)